# Facebook RegisterCallback not working properly

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-studio, facebook-graph-api

I'm making an app named "BrandShopping". The app is intended for online delivery and shopping. That's why I need different login methods so the user can choose what they feel is most comfortable.

The problem I am having is with my Facebook login. I don't quite understand what I am doing wrong. I am mostly having problems with the `RegisterCallback()` function.

The problem is that the app is specified to `RegisterCallback()` with the Login Button (in this case, `RegisterWithFacebookBtn`). In the `OnSuccess()` method, I specified the app to call a method named `FetchUserData()` which is supposed to read the user's info from the Facebook database. Later in that method, I made the app check if the user is logged in. If this is `true`: `goto AccountinfoActivity` (another activity) but it never does.

I've tried debugging the app but I cannot understand what is wrong with the program. I do have a toast that is supposed to display if the `registerCallback()` succeeds but it does not show the toast.

My code is as below:

```
public class LoginOrSignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button LoginBtn, RegisterWithEmailBtn, RegisterWithGoogleBtn;
    private String Tag;
    private ProgressDialog LoadingBar;
    private LoginButton RegisterWithFacebookBtn;

    private FirebaseDatabase firebasedatabase = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private DatabaseReference database = firebasedatabase.getReference();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_or_signup);

        LoadinGUI(); //LOAD IN THE GRAPHICAL USER INTERFACE

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
          .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
          .requestEmail()
          .build();

        LoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginOrSignupActivity.this, LogInActivity.class));
            }
        });

        RegisterWithEmailBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginOrSignupActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));
            }
        });


        RegisterWithFacebookBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //REGISTRATION WITH FACEBOOK
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              SignInWithFacebook();
            }
        });
    }

    private void SignInWithFacebook(){ //FOR FACEBOOK LOGIN

        CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        RegisterWithFacebookBtn.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginOrSignupActivity.this, "Part one succeded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
                    FetchUserData(accessToken);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            }
        });
    }

    // FOR FACEBOOK LOGIN, ALSO SAVES TO THE FIREBASE DATABSE
    private void FetchUserData(final AccessToken accessToken){ 
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(
              JSONObject object, GraphResponse response
            ) {
              try {
                String name = object.getString("name");
                String email = object.getString("email");
                // ADD MORE HERE

                /* WHEN EVERYTHING IS DONE AND SUCCEEDS, 
                 *   GOTO ACCOUNTINFOACTIVITY ACTIVITY; MAY NEED TO BE
                 * MODIFIED LATER ON 
                 */
                if(accessToken != null) {
                  startActivity(new Intent(LoginOrSignupActivity.this, AccountInfoActivity.class));
                }
              } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
            }
        });

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fileds", "id,name,emai");
    }
```

any and all help would be very appreciated

Comment: Duplicate of your own previous question, [I can't get Facebook to Login Properly with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57097748/i-cant-get-facebook-to-login-properly-with-java)

Comment: i know... got no help on that one...

Answer (score 1):

Have you added this in your Activity?

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Comment: yes i have. its just removed so the code is easier to read :/

Comment: try to put a log in onError() method and see the error.

Comment: you may get Unexpected call to LoginManager.onActivityResult in onError() method